# unable to set series data in report builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

i am using report builder for making reports, i have data for x axis
i want to have month with year but its not coming way i want.

data i have

```
    Total Clients   title   month1  Month   Year    CI_UniqueID name    CollectionID    Installed / Not Applicable  Required    Unknown Compliant%  NotCompliant%
2   SUG_2017_01_P1_RFC3456  01  Jan 2017    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_E586ED3A-EDD5-4145-98FB-C0B373F7E4CA  all sccm servers    CAS00014    2   0   0   100 0
2   SUG_2017_04_P1_RFC3103  04  Apr 2017    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_2722FDDB-6D6B-407F-A0CE-063372571E82  all sccm servers    CAS00014    2   0   0   100 0
2   SUG_2017_06_P1_RFC3123  06  June    2017    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_3063A272-0DF9-4033-94E2-C52AF1CFD4BC  all sccm servers    CAS00014    2   0   0   100 0
2   SUG_2017_10_P1_RFC3103  10  Oct 2017    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_9C3F338B-E8BA-4AB5-8ECF-1EA8729825DA  all sccm servers    CAS00014    0   0   2   0   100
2   SUG_2017_11_P1_RFC3103  11  Nov 2017    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_B42D69FC-2564-4542-8D5B-F5348A4080FF  all sccm servers    CAS00014    0   0   2   0   100
2   SUG_2017_12_P1_RFC3103  12  Dec 2017    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_5C3AD217-7747-4BAC-AD06-3851014BCB94  all sccm servers    CAS00014    0   0   2   0   100
2   SUG_2018_01_P1_RFC3103  01  Jan 2018    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_A49E2378-BCB6-40BE-BE84-735CCFBEE43F  all sccm servers    CAS00014    2   0   0   100 0
2   SUG_2018_02_P1_RFC3118  02  Feb 2018    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_E6CBD108-2B1C-4C94-85F8-57174BEC34C4  all sccm servers    CAS00014    2   0   0   100 0
2   SUG_2018_03_P1_RFC3128  03  Mar 2018    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_6AA69C57-9532-4ED1-BA40-1540C840BD69  all sccm servers    CAS00014    2   0   0   100 0
2   SUG_2018_05_P1_RFC3104  05  May 2018    ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_D3A10469-5DE5-4998-9C59-877D3BC7225F  all sccm servers    CAS00014    2   0   0   100 0
```

chart iam getting for  x axis is

[image]

i want on x axis it should come year wise first 2017 months and then 2018.
for jan 2017 it should give separate bar for jan 2018 it should give separate

please find latest chart all i want is separate jan barchart

[image]

Comment: ok so i got sorting part going in category property now my only concern is to got jan bar separate of 2017 and 2018

Comment: can you tell me how to sort bar data

Comment: in category group properties remove group expression you will get all months repetitive as well

Answer (score 0):

in category group properties remove group expression you will get all months repetitive as well